# "Did the Austrian man [...] when he did the highest skydive?" or "Did an Austrian man [...]"

Tags: articles

I was solving some English tests when I stumbled upon this. I said "the" but my English teacher insisted on "an". I was unable to find anything similar in a corpus.

Should it be "the" or "an"?

The full sentence:

> Did **the/an/a** Austrian man fly faster than light or sound when he did the highest skydive?

Comment: In this case it seems like a particular Austrian man (the one who did the highest skydive) is being referred to, so I would say that 'the' is correct.

Comment: I would also say 'an' could also be correct, since it may not be referencing a man in particular but rather a collection of people.

Especially if it did not specify that the man is Austrian, the indefinite article would be preferred, or perhaps not even necessary.

e.g. "Did man fly faster than light or sound when he did the highest skydive?"
Of course here, man refers to mankind, and is just gender biased.

Comment: I'm curious why you thought the correct answer would be "the" – was that just a guess? (By the way, did the test question have other text besides this sentence? Because, as others have said, whether or not _an_ or _the_ is more appropriate largely depends on the context – in other words, on what was said beforehand.)

Comment: @J.R. no context, just this sentence. Also, I thought "the" because it was referring to the Austrian man that made the the highest skydive. It isn't any random Austrian man, it is the Austrian who made the highest skydive (if it was just skydive and not highest skydive, I'd use an, but there can only be one that reached the highest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of answer the person asking the question is looking for.

Let's assume the person is very ignorant about the speed of light, and wants to know which barrier was broken during the skydive:

> Did the Austrian man fly faster than **light or sound** when he did the highest skydive?
>   (Answer: He flew faster than *sound*. You can't reach the speed of light in a skydive.)

In this case, I would say that "the" is the correct answer. We are not talking about any man, we are talking about the skydiver.

However, if we were asking about something else, we might easily change the article:

> Did an Austrian **man** fly faster than than the speed of sound when making the highest skydive?
>   (Answer: No, it was an Austrian *woman* who broke the speed of sound while skydiving.)
>
> Did an **Austrian** man fly faster than the speed of sound when he did the highest skydive?
>   (Answer: No, it was a *Hungarian* man who did the highest skydive.)

Then again, we might not:

> Did the Austrian man fly faster than the speed of sound when he did the **highest** skydive?
>   (Answer: No, he broke the sound barrier when he did the *third highest* skydive. He never broke the sound barrier when he set the altitude record – he opened his parachute too soon.)

Given the way the question is worded, I'm inclined to think your teacher is correct, because I think the "light or sound" part is a crucial part of the question. That said, I also think that, unless there is extra information in the test booklet that isn't provided here, this could be considered a rather confusing test question.

Comment: "We are not talking about any man, we are talking about the skydiver." -- I'm afraid I don't understand. Is it okay to use "the" even if that's the first mention of that man, and the speaker is unsure that his hearer will be able to guess the identity of the man?

Comment: @CowperKettle Sometimes a noun takes _the_ because of what identifies it subsequently. But I'm not sure whether _when he did the highest skydive_ can function like that.

Comment: @CowperK - You tell me. _The First National Bank across from the library was robbed at noon yesterday. Twenty minutes later, the robber was apprehended while crossing the bridge that spans over the river while heading out of the city limits._ I used the word "the" half a dozen times there – anything confusing?

Comment: It was from a "quiz" in a Pearson book BTW. http://imgur.com/Jjhaesh

Answer (score 0):

The question is tricky and it obviously depends on the context.

Let's say "Arnold Schwarzenegger" is the most famous skydiver in Austria and no other Austrians could match him in terms of the height from which he skydives. Then, obviously using "the" is correct as most people would know that  Arnold Schwarzenegger" is being referred to. Or if that particular Austrian man was mentioned in the previous conversation, using "the" is correct.

Then, the question is about the fact whether he flew faster or slower than light or sound. The answer would be

> Yes, he flew faster.

or

> No, he didn't fly faster.

However, if there are more than one skydivers from Austria and other countries who are famous for trying to achieve the highest point in skydiving, you can't use the definite article, "the" as it would indicate the known skydiver as in the above Arnold example.

The indefinite article "an" in the sentence means basically "one unknown" and the questioner is interested in knowing the nationality of the skydiver. The question could be rephrased to:

> Did an Austrian man or Australian man (or any other man from other countries) fly faster than ...?

Obviously we can guess there were multiple skydivers from Austria, Australia or other countries.

The answer would be

> Yes, an Austrian man did.

or

> No, it was not
>   an Austrian man. An Australian man (or any other countryman) did.